# Count unique values in each dataframe's column and transform to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

```
data = {'Col1': [1, 2, 2, 3, 1],
    'Col2': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

i want to get a dictionary like:

```
{'Col1': {1:2, 2:2, 3:1},
 'Col2': {'A':2, 'B':2, 'C':1}
```

without using any kind of `loop`, `apply` or `agg` method.

I have tried something like this:

```
count_matrix = df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts()
count_matrix = count_matrix.unstack(0)
count_matrix = count_matrix.to_dict()
```

but it does not work, because it inserts `nan` value to fill blanks when unstacking.

Comment: check pd.unique https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pure pandas without explicit loops, you can go with [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html), [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df.agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict()).to_dict()
```

Or, overriding the loop limitation with `map`:

```
dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1].value_counts().to_dict()), df.items()))
```

Output:

```
{'Col1': {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1}, 'Col2': {'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}}
```

Comment: The `map` method really helps me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @jkklbbnn `map()` just hides the loop internally and IMHO it's harder to read than normal list/dict comprehension.

Comment: @AndrejKesely well this is the constraint... but this kind of constraint is most often stupid and really not a good way to teach programming. I believe the `agg` approach or a dictionary comprehension is the most pythonic.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution:

```
{col: df[col].value_counts().to_dict() for col in df}
```

Output:

```
{'Col1': {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1}, 'Col2': {'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}}
```

Comment: I want to get the unique value count in every column without using any loop, apply or agg

Comment: Please, see my updated code, which I think does what you are wanting.

Comment: I have a lot of columns, so it is not really the way i want

Comment: Why? What is the reason? Speed? Notice that `groupby` tends to be slower than `list comprehension`.

Comment: It is a practise to use pandas. The requirement is not using **loop**, **agg** or **apply**